# BufferReader.readline() block PrinterWriter.println()

Tags: java, android, sockets, buffer

After creating socket connection in Android App, i can't write in buffer after reading.

This is an example for establishing connection with my Server:

```
//...
try{    
    socket = new Socket(IP, Port);
    out = new  PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
    in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    //ask for connection
    out.println(req1);
    //server send me a nonce
    result=in.readLine().toString();
    //encrypting nonce with specific alghorithm 
    passwd=Password.get_Passwd(result);
    //sending password 
    out.println(passwd); //here out.println doesn't write 
    //...
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        socket.close();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   
//...
```

So can any one help me solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't write?? Did you try adding a breakpoint and debugging??? Did the control reach that line??? Or was it blocked in one of the previous lines itself???

Comment: there is nothing blocked.... only the second println doesn't make anything ... all worked fun just when i read the buffer i can't write in it again only if i recreate my socket, unfortunately in that case new nonce generated and new password needed ....

Comment: readLine() can return null. You aren't checking for that, so your code is liable to NPEs.

Comment: yes that's it, it return null ... so any other ideas ?